# How to avoid auto launch force stopped application in Android 13

Tags: battery-life, android-12, android-13, sleep, force-stop

I am using `Moto G72` which comes with `Android 12`. I was happy with `Android 12`. I am using the `Greenify` application to force stop unwanted applications. Whenever we click the icons of the unwanted applications, then only the applications wake up from sleep. Recently I got an `Android 13` update. After updating, force stopped applications automatically wake up after a certain amount of time. I changed the battery usage of unwanted applications to Restricted. But no use. I can see the battery drain is more in Android 13 than 12.

Comment: Self promotion: [How to stop background apps on Android?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/stop_background_apps_in_android)